# How to change the Model Target in iOS sample VuforiaSample

Tags: model, target, vuforia

I am using vuforia-sdk-ios-10-16-3 native sample. I generated a model target myOwnModelTarget. I changed the sample's model target with my own.

auto modelTargetConfig = vuModelTargetConfigDefault();

//modelTargetConfig.databasePath = "VuforiaMars_ModelTarget.xml";

modelTargetConfig.databasePath = "myOwnModelTarget.xml";

//modelTargetConfig.targetName = "VuforiaMars_ModelTarget";

modelTargetConfig.targetName = "myOwnModelTarget";

modelTargetConfig.activate = VU_TRUE;

When I run the sample, the following error is displayed.

023-07-23 17:21:07.539185+0900 VuforiaSample[8667:2293169] ERROR/AR(8667) Failed to load database 'myOwnModelTarget.xml'.

2023-07-23 17:21:07.539584+0900 VuforiaSample[8667:2293169] ERROR/AR(8667) Creating ModelTargetObserver...FAILED

Could you anyone help me how to change a target model?

Comment: vuEngineCreateModelTargetObserver fourth argument is an VuModelTargetCreationError enum which on failure should contain some extra information on your actual problem